# background color does not change for UILabel

Tags: iphone, uilabel

I have a label that I want to change the background color of when a button is selected. It works fine when I first enter the view but when I leave the view and return, it no longer works even though I can still access the label by its tag and read its text.

```
UILabel *labelToFlip = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:labelTag];
if (button.selected)
{    
    NSLog(@"selected");
    NSLog(@"label text:%@:%d", labelToFlip.text, labelToFlip.tag);
    [labelToFlip setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [labelToFlip setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```

This is how I return to my view. Again I can get to the label and read the text with no problem, just can't change the background color or text color.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.navigationController.parentViewController
                                     animated:YES];
```

Comment: I think you might be doing something horribly wrong here.  With the code "[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.navigationController.parentViewController animated:YES];" This will create a cyclic loop with the navigation controller, if you add it's parent to itself.

Comment: sorry, I may have not have been clear. That code is called from a different view, a child view so to speak. Is that still a problem?

Comment: Yep that will still be an issue. Say you add your navigation controller to your instance of UIWindow in your app delegate then you push some UIViewControllers onto this UINavigationController, when you call "self.navigationController" in a UIViewController that you have pushed into the navigation stack this will return the instance of your UINavigationController that you added this view to.
Then you are calling parentViewController on your UINavigationController, this in what I have described above would be the UIWindow of your App Delegate.

Comment: in case anyone is interested, my label problem was fixed by adding it as a subview. - thanks all for viewing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand out your code and perhaps make more sense of what I have tried to comment about above.

```
UINavigationController* navigationController = [self navigationController];

UIViewController* parentViewControllerForNavigationController = [navigationController parentViewController];
```

Then in your code you are then adding the parent ViewController to the child ViewController.

```
[navigationController pushViewController:parentViewControllerForNavigationController animated:YES];
```

Which no matter where you perform this is going to cause some major problems. I think you aren't quite understanding how a UINavigationController works. The simple explanation is that it's really just an iterator for an list (or a queue if you prefer) of UIViewControllers (or subclasses of UIViewControllers).  In effect the way you are adding the parent view controller to the navigation controller is causing a replication of the navigation controller.

The code:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Simply removes the last item from the list, it will call the release and dealloc methods on the UIViewController that is at the end of the UINavigationController stack. Which will cause the App to animate back to the previous view (as the animate argument is 'YES'), you do not need to push another view onto the navigation stack here at all, which is what it seems like you are trying to do.

However if you were for example trying to perform some navigation manipulation such as:
You have three view controllers, UIViewController A,B and C.
The Root View Controller is A. You push B onto the navigation controller then perform some function in B and want view controller C to be pushed onto the navigation stack, but when you press back in view C you would like to be presented with View A and not View B you could manipulate the array returned by calling [self navigationController] viewControllers] and removing the second last object and resizing the array and then calling [self navigationController] setViewControllers:"resizedArray"] but I would have this functionality happen in the viewDidAppear function in view controller C's implementation.